# get ANT_HOME for configured ant in shell

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have an ant installation configured in jenkins (Manage Jenkins->Ant Installations). I have a build step `Execute shell` where I need to call ant targets. How can I get ANT_HOME for specific ant installation or configure that shell needs to have ANT_HOME for specific installation?

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_HOME is setting when you select an ANT Step, the shell script will use the ANT_HOME setted on the server as environment variable. 
A solution is write the ANT_HOME value during an ANT task on a file on the workspace.

```
<echo message="${ant.home}" file="anthome.txt" />
```

The shell script read this file and use it for launch ant targets.

```
FOR /F %i IN (anthome.txt) DO SET ANT_HOME=%i
```

In any case perhaps is easier to have a ant script for launch other ant targets that your approach.